# Can a dense set contain isolated points?

Tags: general-topology

I was interested in this question, can a dense set contain an isolated point, because I was reading into the lexicographic order topology on the unit square.

I read in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square#cite_note-CEIT-1) that:

> $S$ is not separable, since the set of all points of the form $(x,\frac{1}{2})$ is discrete but is uncountable.

I do understand why $T=\{ (x,\frac{1}{2} ) \,|\,\,\, 0\leq x \leq 1 \}$ is discrete, but I don't see how $T$ being uncountable assists us in showing $S$ is not separable? I thought maybe this is because a dense set cannot contain any isolated points? But I'm not sure on that. If anyone can clarify here, it'll be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That explanation is very badly written. It isn’t the fact that the set is discrete that shows that $S$ is not separable: it’s the fact that the points of the set can be enclosed in pairwise disjoint open intervals, e.g., the intervals $\big(\langle x,0\rangle,\langle x,1\rangle\big)$ for $x\in[0,1]$. If $S$ had a countable dense subset $D$, each of these uncountably many intervals would have to contain a different member of $D$ which is obviously impossible.

There are many separable spaces with uncountable discrete subsets, even uncountable **closed** discrete subsets. One is the [tangent disk space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane), also known as the Moore or Niemytzki plane.

As for your original question: if a space has isolated points, they must necessarily be part of any dense subset. This is clear from the fact that if $p$ is isolated, $\{p\}$ is an open set, and the only point that it contains is $p$.

Comment: Also the [Sorgenfrey plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane).

Comment: @Daniel: And Mrówka’s $\Psi$.

Comment: I only mentioned the Sorgenfrey plane because I think that's the most familiar one. That's an example even non-topologists sometimes know.

Comment: @Daniel: I figured as much, and I agree. I mentioned $\Psi$ because (for whatever reason) it was the first one that actually occurred to me.

Answer (score 4):

Even if $X$ has no isolated points, it is possible that a dense set $S$ has isolated points. For example if $X$ is indiscrete, then any one-point set is dense and this point is isolated. Or if $X=A\times B$ where $A$ is discrete and $B$ is indiscrete (but $|B|>1$), the the graph of any function $A\to B$  is dense in $X$ and is a discrete space.